# Counting density of Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, statistics, lexical-analysis

I created a tool to examine Python 3 source code. It measures the density of program. More info in docstring (to not reinvent the wheel).

What could be done to increase its usability? Any edge cases that I didn't think of?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

'''
Module counts how dense is Python source code in
terms of lexical entities per LoC.
'''

import ast


def traverse(node, line_nos):
    '''
    go through the AST and count lines
    '''
    children = list(ast.iter_child_nodes(node))

    try:
        current_line = node.lineno
    except AttributeError:
        current_line = 0

    count = 1
    line_nos.update([current_line])

    if len(children) == 0:
        return 1

    for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(node):
        count += traverse(child, line_nos)

    return count


def count_code_entities(source):
    '''
    parse the source&count
    '''
    line_nos = set()
    tree = ast.parse(source)

    # len - 1 to compensate for default value 0
    # which cannot hold any code 
    return traverse(tree, line_nos), len(line_nos) - 1


def main():
    '''
    parsin&stuff
    '''
    from argparse import ArgumentParser, FileType
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('infile',
                        help='source file to analyze',
                        type=FileType(),
                        default='-',
                        nargs='?',)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    with args.infile as file:
        source = file.read()
        name = file.name

    count, number = count_code_entities(source)
    print(name, ': ', round(count/number, 4), 'entities/line of code')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Damn, this is pretty good, I can only think of `getattr` rather than a `try except`. So I look forward to the answers to this question! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. The docstrings are vague. Documentation needs to be *precise* and *complete*. It should answer questions like "what arguments should I pass?" and "what does it return?" For example, "go through the AST and count lines" should become something like, "Return the number of nodes in the AST rooted at `node`, and update the set `line_nos` with the line numbers of these nodes, plus the line number 0 if any node has no line number."
2. It's not clear that the "plus the line number 0 if any node has no line number" behaviour is needed. Instead of doing this and then having to subtract one later to compensate, why not avoid adding the line number 0 in the first place?
3. When traversing an AST, it's often convenient to use the [`ast.NodeVisitor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) class, like this:

   ```
   class DensityVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
       """AST visitor that accumulates the count of nodes and the set of line
       numbers in the AST.
       """
       def __init__(self):
           self.node_count = 0
           self.line_numbers = set()

       def visit(self, node):
           self.node_count += 1
           try:
               self.line_numbers.add(node.lineno)
           except AttributeError:
               pass
           self.generic_visit(node)

       @property
       def density(self):
           """The density of code (nodes per line) in the visited AST."""
           return self.node_count / len(self.line_numbers)
   ```

   and then in `main` you'd write:

   ```
   visitor = DensityVisitor()
   visitor.visit(ast.parse(source))
   print('density (nodes/line) =', round(visitor.density, 4)))
   ```

   **Update:** Why would you prefer [`ast.NodeVisitor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) over explicitly walking the tree using [`ast.iter_child_nodes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.iter_child_nodes) plus recursion? Well, because of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) — the logic for walking the tree is delegated to the [`ast.NodeVisitor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) base class, and you only have to specify what happens at each node. (Another possibility would be to use [`ast.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.walk).)

Answer (score 8):

Great job overall, the code looks quite clean.

There are only few things that I would mention:

- you can calculate `count` using `sum()` one-liner
- `if len(children) == 0:` can be replaced with `if not children:`
- and, we don't actually need to handle this base case, since we are going to use `sum` with `+1`, and in case of `children` being an empty list, we'll have 1 as a result naturally
- [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id33) need to be in triple double-quotes, start with a capital letter and end with a dot
- move import statements to the top of the module
- `file` is not a good variable name since it shadows the built-in `file` keyword
- let's rename `main` function to a more readable `report_code_density`
- use a formatted string to print out the report - it will be a bit better in terms of having the report printed consistently on both Python2.x and Python3.x
- you can use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) instead of `try/except` for the `lineno` (credits to @peilonrayz)

Improved code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""Module counts how dense is Python source code in terms of lexical entities per LoC."""

from argparse import ArgumentParser, FileType
import ast


def traverse(node, line_nos):
    """Goes through the AST and count lines."""
    current_line = getattr(node, 'lineno', 0)
    line_nos.update([current_line])

    return sum(traverse(child, line_nos) for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(node)) + 1


def count_code_entities(source):
    """Parses the source & counts."""
    line_nos = set()
    tree = ast.parse(source)

    # len - 1 to compensate for default value 0, which cannot hold any code
    return traverse(tree, line_nos), len(line_nos) - 1


def report_code_density():
    """Main execution block of the program."""
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('infile',
                        help='Source file to analyze',
                        type=FileType(),
                        default='-',
                        nargs='?')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    with args.infile as source_file:
        source = source_file.read()
        name = source_file.name

    count, number = count_code_entities(source)
    print('{name}: {value} entities/line of code'.format(name=name, value=round(count / number, 4)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    report_code_density()
```

And, here is the `pylint` report (with default settings) for the improved code:

```
$ pylint test.py
Report
======
24 statements analysed.

Global evaluation
-----------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10
```

Comment: Thanks for your remarks. I'll wait if something else pop up. My original code had 10.0/10 pylint score though

Comment: @enedil thanks. I think that Gareth's NodeVisitor based version looks much cleaner than both of our versions.